# How to find number of tables in a database and size of database Pervasive

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql, actian

I am using Pervasive Control Center v11.  How do I find the size of an entire database and the number of tables?

The following results in error:'error in expression'

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_database_size('RECORDS'))
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to get the size of the database for a Pervasive PSQL database through a SQL Statement.  You can look at the actual files on disk to see the size. 
You can get a count of the tables by executing the following statement:

```
select count(*) from x$file
```

This count will include the system tables (X$XXXX).

The `pg_` functions aren't Pervasive PSQL functions but are PostgreSQL functions and won't work with a Pervasive / Actian database.